# Getting SMTP Errror which trying to send mail vai php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

This is my first time using PHP mailer. So please assist if you can.
I am sending a mail to merchants when orders are made on their products.

I have downloaded and installed phpmailer on my code,
Done all the includes as dircted in the repo, but when I run the Code
I GET SMTP class not found. please what is my oversight? Thank you.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

function mail_merchants_and_shoply($cart_code){
        

        require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
        require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

        $conn = $this -> connection;
        $merchant_sent = false;
        $shoply_sent = false;
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM business_account ORDER BY business_id DESC")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['business_id'];
            $stat = "NEW";
            $email = $row['email_add'];
            $name = $row['business_name'];
            $c_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cart_db WHERE business_id = '$id' AND cart_code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cart_code)."'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $merchant_mail_body = "<h2>NEW ORDER</h2><ul>";
            while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($c_query)){
                $p_id = $arr['product_id'];
                $p_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$p_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $p_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query);
                $image = $p_arr['product_image1_url'];
                $price = $p_arr['product_price'];
                $name = $p_arr['product_name'];

                $image = "<img src = 'https://www.shoply.ng/backend/$image' style = 'max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px'/>";

                $merchant_mail_body.="<li>$name</li> <li>$image</li> <li> $price</li>";
            }
            
            $merchant_mail_body .="</ul>";

            $mail_subject = "NEW SHOPLY ORDER";
            // $mailHead = implode("\r\n", ["MIME-Version:1.0","Content-type:text/html; charset =utf-8"]);

            $mailHead = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $mailHead .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            
            // Additional headers
            $mailHead .= 'From: Shoply<orders@shoply.ng>' . "\r\n";
            // if(mail($email, $mail_subject, $merchant_mail_body, $mailHead)){
            //     $merchant_sent = true;
            // }

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            try {
                //Server settings
                $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
                $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
                $mail->Host       = 'mail.shoply.ng';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username   = 'myusername';                     //SMTP username
                $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                               //SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
                $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
            
                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('orders@shoply.ng', 'SHOPLY');
                $mail->addAddress('el1harolds@gmail.com', '');     //Add a recipient
                // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
                // $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
                // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
                // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
            
                //Attachments
                // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
                // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name
            
                //Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = 'NEW SHOPLY ORDER';
                $mail->Body    = $merchant_mail_body;
   
            
                $mail->send();
                $merchant_sent = true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
               $merchant_sent = false;
            }






            $s_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cart_db WHERE cart_code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cart_code)."'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $o_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cart_code)."'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $o_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($o_query);
            $location = $o_arr['delivery_location'];
            $phone = $o_arr['delivery_phone'];
            $user_fname = $_SESSION['user_fname'];
            $shoply_mail_body = "<h2>NEW ORDER</h2> FROM: $user_fname <ul>
            <li><b>Address:</b> $location</li>
            <li><b>Phone Number: </b>$phone</li>";
            // $f_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($s_query);
            // $customer_id = $f_arr['customer_id'];
            // $c_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id= '$customer_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            // $c_arr[]
            

            
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($s_query)){
                $p_id = $row['product_id'];
                $p_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$p_id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $p_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query);
                $image = $p_arr['product_image1_url'];
                $price = $p_arr['product_price'];
                $name = $p_arr['product_name'];
                $image = "<img src = 'https://www.shoply.ng/backend/$image' style = 'max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px'/>";

                $shoply_mail_body.="<li>$name</li> <li>$image</li> <li> $price</li>";
            }  
            $shoply_mail_body .="</ul>";
            // $email = "sales@shoply.ng";
            // $mail_subject = "NEW SHOPLY ORDER";
            // // $mail_head = implode("\r\n", ["MIME-Version:1.0","Content-type:text/html; charset =utf-8"]);

            // $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            // $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            
            // // Additional headers
            // $headers .= 'From: Shoply<orders@shoply.ng>' . "\r\n";


            // if(mail($email, $mail_subject, $shoply_mail_body, $headers)){
            //     $shoply_sent = true;
            // }

            


            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            try {
                //Server settings
                $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
                $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
                $mail->Host       = 'mail.shoply.ng';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username   = 'myusername';                     //SMTP username
                $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                               //SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
                $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
            
                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('orders@shoply.ng', 'SHOPLY');
                $mail->addAddress('sales@shoply.ng', '');     //Add a recipient
                // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
                // $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
                // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
                // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
            
                //Attachments
                // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
                // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name
            
                //Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = 'NEW ORDER';
                $mail->Body    = $shoply_mail_body;
   
            
                $mail->send();
                $shoply_sent = true;
                
                    return true;
                
    
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the namespace import. Add this at the top:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

Separately, learn to use composer. Your function will crash the second time you call it because you'll be loading duplicate classes.

Comment: Okay. Thanks I will surely be  looking into composer ASAP.